# Receiving parameter in controller from Ajax call in Spring

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

In my spring project I am sending request through Ajax call like this:

```
function doAjaxPost(currentPage) {

    var appName = document.searchForm.txtZipFile.value;  
    var e = document.getElementById("selectStatus");
    var appStatus = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;        


    $.ajax({  
     type : "GET",   
     url : "http://localhost:8080/ preListOnSearch.do",   
      data : "currentPage=" + currentPage + "&appName=" + appName + "&appStatus="  
       + appStatus, 
       cache: false,

     success : function(response) {           
      alert(response);   
     },  

     error : function(e) {  
      alert('Error: ' + e);   
     } 

    }); 
   }
```

And in my controller I wrote method like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/preListOnSearch", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String preTestDataolx(@PathVariable("siteId") String siteId,                  @PathVariable(value = "currentPage") String currentPage,
         @RequestParam(value = "appStatus") String appStatus) {
    System.out.println(appStatus);
    return "/preTestData";  
}
```

But this give me error. When I remove RequestParams from method definition it works fine. So I just want to know that how can I access ajax call parameter in controller.

Comment: it works fine no error is there

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the data as a JS object:

```
$.ajax({  
   type : "GET",   
   url : "http://localhost:8080/ preListOnSearch.do",   
   data : {currentPage: currentPage, appName: appName, appStatus: appStatus},
   cache: false,
```